# Behavior of count array

Tags: java, arrays, string, char

count is the char array and it stores characters only.

`count[str.charAt(i)]++;`

what exactly happening in the above line?

`count[str.charAt(i)] == 1`

How integer comparable with char as count is char array ?

Pasted code below for find out the first non repeated character in string.It is absolutely working.

Can anyone answer my two questions mentioned above?

```
class GFG { 
 static final int NO_OF_CHARS = 256; 
 static char count[] = new char[NO_OF_CHARS]; 

/* calculate count of characters  
   in the passed string */
 static void getCharCountArray(String str)  
 { 
     for (int i = 0; i < str.length();  i++) 
     {  //System.out.println(count[str.charAt(i)]+"   Before");
          count[str.charAt(i)]++; 
        // System.out.println(count[str.charAt(i)]+"   After");
     }
 } 

/* The method returns index of first non-repeating 
   character in a string. If all characters are repeating  
   then returns -1 */
static int firstNonRepeating(String str) 
{ 
    getCharCountArray(str); 
    int index = -1, i; 

    for (i = 0; i < str.length();  i++) 
    { 
        if (count[str.charAt(i)] == 1) 
        { 
            index = i; 
            break; 
        }    
    }   

  return index; 
} 

// Driver method 
public static void main (String[] args) 
{ 
    String str = "geeksforgeeks"; 
    int index =  firstNonRepeating(str); 

    System.out.println(index == -1 ? "Either all characters are repeating or string " + 
               "is empty" : "First non-repeating character is " +  str.charAt(index)); 
}
```

}

Comment: What language is this? Please edit your question to add the correct tag. And please take some time to refresh [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: **1.** It will use the numeric value of a character of `s` as an index to increment the value in the array.  Note that this will increment the `char` returned by `count[...]` but not the value in the array itself so `count` will always only have `0` in it. **2.** A `char` is a numeric value that also have a visual representation based on the encoding you choose.

Answer (score 0):

As per Oracle's docs:

> The char data type is a single 16-bit Unicode character. It has a minimum value of > >'\u0000' (or 0) and a maximum value of '\uffff' (or 65,535 inclusive).

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

For this purpose, you can think of it as a 16-bit unsigned (i.e. positive) integer. Therefore, the code `char c = 1;` is equivalent to `char c = (int) 1;`, due to Java's automatic conversion between types. This is similar to how `long l = 1;`, despite `1` being an integer primitive, since the Java language understands that you probably wanted a `long` instead of an `int`.

Therefore, `count[i] == 1` behaves exactly as if you had defined is as an `int[]`, and checks the numeric value of the bytes at that index to see if they equal `1`;

If instead, you are trying to check if that index contains the **character** 1, you could try `count[i] == '1';` (note single quotes, for a character literal instead of a string literal).

Answer (score 0):

So, the following code will iterate each character in a `String` and based on the numerical value of the character, explain by [cameron1024 answer's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57159266/4391450), increment a counter.

```
for (int i = 0; i < str.length();  i++) 
{     //System.out.println(count[str.charAt(i)]+"   Before");
      count[str.charAt(i)]++; 
      // System.out.println(count[str.charAt(i)]+"   After");
}
```

Well, in theory because you need to update the array to increment properly :

```
count[str.charAt(i)] = count[str.charAt(i)]++; 

//Same as
char tmp = count[str.charAt(i)];
count[str.charAt(i)] + 1;
count[str.charAt(i)] = tmp;
```

But also use the correct increment operator because this one will return the original value and not the result

```
count[str.charAt(i)] = ++count[str.charAt(i)]; 

//Same as
count[str.charAt(i)] = count[str.charAt(i)] + 1;
```

Of couse, you can simplify with

```
for (int i = 0; i < str.length();  i++) 
{
    char c = str.charAt(i);
    count[c] = ++count[c]; 
}
```

Or even better

```
for( char c : str.toCharArray())
{
    count[c] = ++count[c]; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Two-byte `char` can be widened to a four-byte `int`. `(char)('a' + 1) == 'b'` and `'a' == 97`.

1. `char` (a 2 byte UTF16 value) has been used as index (`count[str.charAt(i)]`), extending it to an int between 0 of 65_535 (0xFFFF).
2. `char` has also been used for counting (`char[] count`) from 0 upto 65_535.

So there are two limitations:

1. A special character can easily exceed the array length: `€` is 0x20AC, `‘` is 0x2018 and `’` is 0x2019.
2. If the `str` would contain more than 65_535 of a same character, the counting overflows.

The algorithm would be cleaner as:

```
Map<Character, Integer> count = str.chars()
    .mapToObj(char.class::cast)
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));
```

It looks as if `char` is assumed to be a `byte` as historically in C/C++. However java was *designed* to deal with full Unicode in String, and `char` being two bytes, in the UTF-16BE format. So java can hold several scripts at the same time.

> count[str.charAt(i)]++;

```
int j = (int')str.charAt(i);
count[j] = ((int)count[j]) + 1;
```

> count[str.charAt(i)] == 1

```
char ch = count[j];
(int)ch == 1
```